# Python get image paths and sizes from a url using BeautifulSoup & PIL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-imaging-library

Ive successfully created a python script that can print all image paths from a specified url:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.example.com/"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

images = soup.find_all('img')

for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src') :
        print(img['src'])
```

What i now want to do is print the image size alongside the printed url using PIL. Ive tried this but it errors:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
import requests

url="https://www.example.com/"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

images = soup.find_all('img')

for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src') :
        ## Get image sizes in PIL
        imgsize = Image.open(requests.get(img, stream=True).raw)
        print(img['src'], imgsize.size)
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: What is the error you got with the last code snippet ?

Comment: do you get error or what? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you use `img` in `requests.get()` ? You should use `img['src']` - `requests.get(img['src'], ...) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `img['src']` instead of `img`

```
requests.get(img['src'], ...).raw
```

Comment: I tested it and it works. @chappers Change `imgsize = Image.open(requests.get(img, stream=True).raw)` to `imgsize = Image.open(requests.get(img['src], stream=True).raw)`. You may need to wrap this code block in a `try except` blocks for handling the malformed urls and urls which are not working.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that works. But i do get an error on some images: PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1145494a0>. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Images are served from a CDN e.g https://i0.wp.com/www.example.com/image.png?fit=1034%2C239&ssl=1. Maybe that causes an issue?

Comment: you could use `print()` to check what you get from server. Maybe it sends warning for bots/scripts/spamers/hackers instead of image. OR maybe it use `hotlink protection` and check header `referer` before sending image - this way it sends image only when you visit original page. But you can set header `referer` in `requests`

Comment: When i print all image paths using the script at the top of my question (above) they print fine. Its only when i try and print the image size it errors.

Comment: as I said - sever may block access to image (using `hotlink protection`) and you get HTML with warning instead of image. OR simply this image doesn't exists on server. But this is different problem - you have to check what you get from `requests.get` before you use it in `Image.open` or you have to use `try/except` to catch it. You can also try to use header `referer` in `requests.get()` to simulate access from original page.